# What non-differentiable functions have subgradient?

Tags: convex-optimization, subgradient

In general, what non-differentiable functions have subgradient? Which non-differentiable functions do not have subgradient?

Does a function have to be convex for subgradient to be defined for that?
How about $$f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}?$$

Comment: As far as I know, subgradient is only defined for convex functions. And the definition is clear enough. I am not getting what yo mean by _does a function have to be convex for subgradient to be defined for that_ $$\;$$ It's a **definition**

Comment: I simply meant if subgradient is only defined for convex functions or non-convex too.

Comment: A function whose domain is a convex set  _and_ has a subgradient at all points in its domain is convex. It is possible for 1) a function with a non-convex domain to have a subgradient on that domain; and 2) a function to have a subgradient on only a subset of its domain. $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ has a subgradient only at the origin; specifically, $\partial f(0)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Practically, however, the notion of subgradients is of effectively no use for non-convex functions.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are many generalisations.

One useful (from an analysis perspective) is the generalised gradient (see Clarke's "Optimization and Nonsmooth Analysis") which is defined for locally Lipschitz functions.

Under reasonable conditions the generalised gradient is the same as the convex subgradient for convex functions.

The square root is not Lipschitz at $x=0$ so it does not have a generalised gradient there.

One defines the generalised directional derivative $d \circ f(x,h) = \limsup_{t \downarrow 0, y \to x} {f(y+th)-(y) \over t}$ and then (in $\mathbb{R}^n$ at least)
$\partial f(x) = \{ g | d \circ f(x,h) \ge \langle g, h \rangle \text {for all } h\}$.

There is a calculus of non smooth analysis which echoes most of the results in analysis,
for example there is a mean value theorem (Lebourg).

There are pleasing derivations of Fritz John conditions, etc, using the non smooth calculus.